# difference between "heritage" and "inheritance"

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between **heritage** and **inheritance** in meaning?

Comment: For one sense of 'inheritance', they are closely synonymous.

Comment: @sumelic "the traditional beliefs, values, customs etc. of a family , country , or society= inheritance" for definition of **heritage**. "money etc. that you receive from someone who was died" for definition of **inheritance**

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Yes that was confusing me.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Heritage refers to the general endowment received by a nation from one generation to the next, whereas inheritance is the term used to describe the assets passed down by one’s own immediate ancestors, i.e. father to son.

Comment: You're not covering alternative senses of 'inheritance', which a good dictionary would provide.

Answer (score -1):

*Heritage* is defined by [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heritage) as:

> something that is handed down from the past, as a tradition:

while *inheritance* is defined [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inheritance?s=t) as

> something that is or may be inherited; property passing at the owner's death to the heir or those entitled to succeed; legacy.

---

So from these definitions, *inheritance* may refer to tangible items typically being money or real estate.

While *heritage* often refers to things which are intangible typically like beliefs, morals and ethical standards.

Comment: @arash If this answers your questions, could you please kindly up vote and accept the answer? If not, please feel free to ask if you need further clarifications

Comment: Why the down vote, and no feedback? I am more than happy to further clarify if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am new to StackExchange, so I do not have any idea how I vote you or someone else, and for the feedback I just wanted to send thank you, but here in comment area it had said no such words for commenting. that's it. well I appreciate your answer a lot.